# Oracle Apex - One user list for several applications

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

In the workspace, I have several applications that are the modules of one tool.
In these applications, I have compatible Authorization Schemes.
To create new users I use a ready APEX solution - Access Control.
However, for the tool (these few applications) to function efficiently, I need all these applications to use one list of users. The creation of a user in one application translates into his existence in other applications.

[Access Ctrl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncvYn.png)

To achieve this, I thought about creating a procedure that would insert into APEX_APPL_ACL_USERS a few new records with the user's data and different application ids (and appropriate update and delete procedures).
However, I don't know if this is a good solution.
How should I achieve this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Don't insert into APEX_APPL_ACL_USERS directly. Instead use the [documented API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/aeapi/APEX_ACL.html#GUID-C59214CB-8138-4CB4-89CC-4CC357A67288). However, I would take a different approach because of the following. ACL user/roles can also be added / removed via the builder > shared components so you have no complete control over that process.

Here is what I would do. Create your own CUSTOM_APPL_ACL_USERS table that you insert user/roles into. Then create a "SYNC_USERS" procedure that compares the rows in your table against the rows in APEX_APPL_ACL_USERS for each app and add/remove user/roles when needed. Modify the screen you're showing to insert in the custom table and run the sync procedure after each modification (or with a schedule, or with a trigger).

--UPDATE--

From your question it sounds you're pretty new to pl/sql (no offense !). The functionality "Application Access Control" was written to manage authorization for a single app. It's not that simple to implement what you want since data needs to be synchronized across multiple apps. My advice would be to create custom authorization (instead of using ACL) with a table holding a row for every user/role combination (or, if you want to denormalize properly: 3 tables: users/roles/user_roles ). Apex is low code, but for custom implementation some pl/sql knowledge is required. Creating a custom authorization scheme will probably be less work than synchronizing acl data.
I can't write your code (well I probably could but I won't), so I suggest you do some research yourself, grab a pl/sql book or course and get to work on it. When you're stuck on something post it here. I'm sure you'll get a decent answer.

Comment: What should the implementation of your idea look like?
1. Creation of my table CUSTOM_APPL_ACL_USERS, with the same exact columns as APEX_APPL_ACL_USERS, and DML operations - attach this table to the appropriate page in the application.
2. Creation of a procedure that compares those two tables, and in case of lack of common, compatible elements, will insert missing records (separate records for each application id) to APEX_APPL_ACL_USERS, how should this procedure look?

Answer (score 0):

Please keep all the user list in separate table along with user name, user password along other required credentials and create a separate Package for Login and assign User initial value in Apex, then change authentication from Apex to custom Authentication.

Then you can use the same package and table for Multiple application.

Comment: Question is about authorization not authentication